# PHP array_unique and rsort issues

Tags: php, arrays, preg-match-all

I am using preg_match_all to pull phone numbers from a thread. This puts them into an array, im applying both rsort and array_unique to the matches variable, however they have no effect what so ever... The array_unique would eliminate matches that only come up from a quote or response duplicate, and the rsort should make the last index the first, the second to last index, second, etc...

```
preg_match_all('~0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}~', $data, $matches) 
$result = array_unique($matches);
rsort($result);
var_dump($result);
```

Output:

```
array
0 => 
array
  0 => string '111-111-1111' (length=12)
  1 => string '222-222-2222' (length=12)
  2 => string '333-333-3333' (length=12)
  3 => string '444-444-4444' (length=12)
  4 => string '555-555-5555' (length=12)
  5 => string '555-555-5555' (length=12)
  6 => string '555-555-5555' (length=12)
```

Needs to be:

```
array
0 => 
array
  0 => string '555-555-5555' (length=12)
  1 => string '444-444-4444' (length=12)
  2 => string '333-333-3333' (length=12)
  3 => string '222-222-2222' (length=12)
  4 => string '111-111-1111' (length=12)
```

Comment: Please add your code to the question

Comment: You are confused with `rsort` and `array_reverse`, you should use `array_reverse` if you want to reverse you array not `rsort`. Also note that `array_reverse` doesn't reverse the original array passed to it, but returns a new reversed array, see [this link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php) for details:

Comment: No, he wants to sort DESC, so rsort..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need the first element in the matches array.

```
preg_match_all('~0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}~', $data, $matches) 
$aList = $matches[0];
$result = array_unique($aList);

rsort($result);
var_dump($result);
```

Answer (score 1):

preg_match_all gives a two dimensional array. you need to have the first element of $matches. to further process it with unique and rsort.